# How do I call a JSX script from a Maya Python script?

Tags: python, jsx, photoshop, maya

I wrote a Python tool that renders all the game assets in a Maya scene as TGAs to a folder.

I also wrote a Photoshop JSX script that, given the folder above, will cycle through all the renders within to resize, comp alpha, create a stroke and save out as PNGs.

```
makeIcons(iconFolderPath, strokeWidth) // JSX function for photoshop
```

How can I, from within the Maya tool in python - launch the JSX script, passing it the render folder string to run in Photoshop? (this is using Maya 2015 btw)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you can figure out how to start the Photoshop executable via command line, passing it the correct script and folder as arguments, you can just replicate this in Python via the `subprocess` module. More specifically `subprocess.Popen()`

Comment: yep, used `subprocess.Popen()` in Blender to run PS scripts. I'm pretty sure you won't be able to simply pass arguments but you can write them to file with py and read in jsx

Comment: I'm sure you can do it with a batch file, but since (and presumably) you're running Photoshop at the same time just save whatever info you need as a text file. Get Python to save the text file and then run the script. I'd help further but my Maya licence has just expired :(